# spark-submit: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.$lessinit$greater$default$6()Lscala/collection/Map;

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, jvm

I'm running a simple scala example on spark. On this line:

```scala
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://login.hpc-lan.recolic.org:7077", "Recolic+Hust BigData Lab")
```

Spark throws:

```
root@ip-172-31-46-127 ~/h/hust-bigdata-lab# spark-submit --master spark://login.hpc-lan.recolic.org:7077 --class net.recolic.hust.bigdata.labx.Main  target/hust-bigdata-labx.jar 
19/11/07 07:37:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.$lessinit$greater$default$6()Lscala/collection/Map;
    at net.recolic.hust.bigdata.labx.Main$.main(Main.scala:10)
    at net.recolic.hust.bigdata.labx.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My pom.xml is [pasted here](https://paste.ee/p/a9i3i). I tried to downgrade to scala 1.10, tried to build a fat jar including all dependencies, tried to use sbt, but none of them solves the problem.

Could you give any suggestions?

-- UPDATE

My spark is 2.4.4 with scala 2.11.12. So I [modified pom.xml](https://paste.ee/p/AAxXh) to use spark sdk 2.4.4. However, still the same error.

Comment: I guess you have a Spark Version mismatch. Please check which Spark version is used where you are running and then use that version related dependencies while building it.

Comment: @RamdevSharma I tried to change spark sdk version, but still no luck. See UPDATE.